# Openfire Server running in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, xmpp, openfire

I need to host an Openfire XMPP Server in a Tomcat servlet container. Openfire itself uses an embedded Jetty Server. Is there any way to launch Openfire in a J2EE container to start it using Tomcat or any other way to accomplish that?

Comment: If the server is embedded, its likely not designed to be deployed into a different server/container.